# Hello guys when i click on the button that is the title i got the same blog for each title

Tags: python, django, bootstrap-modal

when i clikc on django title i get django post and when i click on javascript title i get django post ether am not using any frame_work and this my blog page i really try every solution i know but Unfortunately nothing happend
[And here an image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I52xv.png)

blog.html

```
 {% for blog in blogs %}
        <div class="col-xl-12 col-md-6 col-xs-12 blog">
            <div class="right-text-content">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
                    <h2 class="sub-heading">{{blog.title|title}}</h2>
                </button>
                <!-- Modal -->

                <div class="modal fade align-self-end mr-3 " id="myModal" tabindex="1" role="dialog"
                    aria-hidden="true">

                    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                        <div class="modal-content">
                            <div class="modal-header">
                                <h5 class="modal-title">{{blog.title|title}}</h5>

                                <h6 class="float-right">{{blog.created_at}}</h6>
                                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                </button>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-body">
                                {{blog.content|linebreaks}}
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-footer">
                                <h5>Created by {{blog.name}}</h5>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>


                <p>
                    <br>
                    <a rel="nofollow noopener" href="{{blog.name_url}}" target="_parent">{{blog.name}}</a>
                    <br>
                    {{blog.content|linebreaks}}
                </p>
                {{blog.created_at}}
            </div>
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import DigitalTeam, Blog


def index(request):
    pers = DigitalTeam.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'index.html', {'pers':pers})

def blog(request):
    pers = DigitalTeam.objects.all()
    blogs = Blog.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'blog.html', {'pers':pers, 'blogs':blogs})
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('blog', views.blog, name='blog'),
]
```

So guys what am i missing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get individual blog details in the modal you need to pass the blog id to the modal as a prop.
It can be done by adding blog.id in the button data-target prop and receive the blog.id in modal id prop.
the solution in given below,

```
{% for blog in blogs %}
<div class="col-xl-12 col-md-6 col-xs-12 blog">
    <div class="right-text-content">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal{{blog.id}}">
            <h2 class="sub-heading">{{blog.title|title}}</h2>
        </button>
        <!-- Modal -->

        <div class="modal fade align-self-end mr-3 " id="myModal{{blog.id}}" tabindex="1" role="dialog"
            aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h5 class="modal-title">{{blog.title|title}}</h5>

                        <h6 class="float-right">{{blog.created_at}}</h6>
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        {{blog.content|linebreaks}}
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <h5>Created by {{blog.name}}</h5>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <p>
            <br>
            <a rel="nofollow noopener" href="{{blog.name_url}}" target="_parent">{{blog.name}}</a>
            <br>
            {{blog.content|linebreaks}}
        </p>
        {{blog.created_at}}
    </div>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```